# Filtering out parts of a relation on osm2pgsql import

Tags: openstreetmap, osm2pgsql

Is there any way with osm2pgsql to filter out members of a relation during the import phase, based upon the tags of the member?

My use case is that I want to gather a set of road cycling relations, but I want to exclude any sections of those relations (i.e. the member ways) that are marked with route=mtb.

I've been trying out the examples of the Flex output mode in osm2pgsql, and it looks like you can include/exclude relations and their tags, but you cannot exclude members from the relations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The new flex version of the main 'openstreetmap-carto' style that is currently in development:

https://github.com/gravitystorm/openstreetmap-carto/pull/4431

contains a definition of a new 'planet_osm_route' table.

Note that this table is non-spatial, see image! It doesn't contain geometries. The idea behind it is that, instead of duplicating the geometries that are already stored in the 'planet_osm_line' table, you can instead dynamically display routes by joining this table with the 'planet_osm_line' table via the route 'member_id' field in the 'planet_osm_route' table, that references the OSM ID of the corresponding geometries in 'planet_osm_line'.

With this new table and capability of flex, it should then be relatively easy to filter out all member ways of a route additionally tagged with 'route=mtb'. It will require some thought and SQL wizardry, but I think it can be done.

[image]